# Executing command line script from Django & Python

Tags: django, screenshot

I'm building a Django management command which is creating website screenshots using Paul Hammond's webkit2png script (http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) and stores them into my DB.

For this command I'm using the 'call' command from 'subprocess'. How do I execute this command in specific directory (temp/ under django project in this case)? My current code looks like this but it doesn't find the script to execute which is stored in my virtualenv site-packages folder:

```
import os

from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.conf import settings
from subprocess import call

# Models
from reviews.models import Shop

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        # Shops
        shops = Shop.objects.all()

        path = os.path.join(settings.SITE_ROOT, '../env/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

        for shop in shops:
            print shop
            command = "cd temp; python %s/webkit2png.py -F %s" % (path, shop.url)
            call([command])

            # Read the screenshot file and insert to model's ImageField
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `cwd` parameter to `call`.  Also I'd recommend normalizing the path before using it.

```
path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(settings.SITE_ROOT, 
    '../env/lib/python2.6/site-packages'))

for shop in shops:
    print shop
    call(["python", path + "/webkit2png.py", "-F", shop.url], cwd="temp")

# Read the screenshot file and insert to model's ImageField
```

`call` takes the same arguments as [Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen).  You might find some more things there that help out as well. Also, it's best to split your command-line tokens up as separate strings in the list passed to `call` and leave the `shell` parameter at its default `False`.  This way, you don't have to worry about shell escaping, quoting, or whatever messing up your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly but : why do you need to use subprocess to call a python script ? You could just look at the "`__main__`" code in the webkit2png.py file, `import` it and use it.

Comment: This is something that I would usually do but the main() code in this case is a bit complex and it saves the results in files.