# Want to find date data in python shell

Tags: python, django, models

I have a model something like this.

```
#models.py
class ItemStatusHistory(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    item = models.ForeignKey(StorageItem)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.status)
```

I want to be able to find the date data using

```
python manage.py shell
```

But I want to keep the unicode object as status. Do I use a filter lookup?

Comment: What do you mean exactly, 'find the date data'?

Comment: I have stored some data for date, contact, item, status, user. I want to be able to see the data I put in for these objects using python manage.py shell. Not the admin.

Comment: Are you asking how to write command-line applications that use the Django ORM?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351951/executing-command-line-script-from-django-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the object from the django db in the usual way and access foo.name_of_attribute:

The example in the django docs should help, see:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

```
 >>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
 >>> p.pub_date
 datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 15, 12, 00, 53)
```

And thats a standard python datetime thing.

Answer (score 0):

When returning date to the python shell you could just use

```
from time import asctime
#print asctime()
```